# Ubuntu will not boot on new ASUS M51AC

Tags: boot, asus, boot-repair

I installed the from the Live CD, and the installation worked. (I choose the 64 bit installation) but when I restart my computer it just goes into the BIOS system. When I select to boot from the drive it just puts me back in the BIOS. I can boot from the Live CD

I used boot-repair and it didn't work and gave me this message to paste:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/6530190/

Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed it correctly and now cant use it , means grub is affected due to any unfortunate cause So Try [Boot-repair-Again](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)  to repair your grub , for doing so you have to boot ubuntu live usb or dvd and after booting click on try-ubuntu.

When desktop screen appears press Ctrl+Alt+t  for opening terminal and run the follwing commands into the terminal -

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)
```

After that the boot-repair window will appear ,in that select Recommended repair option . After completion restart your pc .it will be fixed.If you need any assistance or anything click on the link mentioned in the answer.

hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

On line `495` of the [Paste](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6530190/), it states `Boot successfully repaired.`

This would lead me to believe that the system is more complicated than I would know how to solve, however before resorting to other methods, I would recommend you [follow these instructions on Grub Repair](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd#.UqH76bVdVCE) from a Live CD, then try to boot again.

If that fails, I regret I cannot help you.